# Oracle Parameters used multiple places in query

Tags: python

I'm trying to pass the same parameters to an oracle query in two separate places in the SQL code.

My code works if I hard code the criteria for table2 like this:

```
# define parameters
years = ['2018','2019']
placeholder= ':d' 
placeholders= ', '.join(placeholder for unused in years)
placeholders

# create cursor
cursor = connection.cursor()

# query
qry = """
select * from table1 
 INNER 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1_id = table2_id    
where table1_year in (%s)
and table2_year in ['2018','2019'] --here's where I say I'm hard coding criteria
""" % placeholders
data = cursor.execute(qry, years)
df = pd.DataFrame(data.fetchall(), columns = [column[0] for column in cursor.description])

# close database connection
connection.close()
```

If I try to use the parameter for table2 like this:

```
qry = """
select * from table1 
 INNER 
  JOIN table2 
    ON table1_id = table2_id    
where table1_year in (%s)
and table2_year in (%s) --part of code I'm having issues with
""" % placeholders
```

I get the following error:

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I can't simply rewrite the SQL because I frequently have to use someone else's code and it wouldn't be feasible to rewrite all of it.

Comment: You wouldn't have to rewrite the SQL, _much_, but could you update your string formatting approach to use `.format()`?

Comment: You have to provide `placeholders` twice if you want to input it twice. Like `% (placeholders, placeholders)`

Comment: @Niklas Mertsch - Your suggestion solved my problem. Do you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: I assume you are referring to ```unused``` on ```for unused in years``` as throwable value. If that is the case you can be more Pythonic writing it as  ```for _ in years```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to fill multiple placeholders, you have to supply the same number of parameters.

```
"one meal: %s" % "sandwich"  # works
"two meals: %s, %s" % "sandwich"  # not working
"two meals: %s, %s" % ("sandwich", "sandwich")  # works
```

NOTE: It is a bad/dangerous thing to use string formatting for the assembly of SQL queries (lookup "SQL Injection"). In your case it is fine, but in general you should use parameterized queries, especially when dealing with input from untrusted sources like user input. You don't want a user to input "2018; DROP TABLE table1;".

Comment: You should make it very clear that this is a _demo_ and that people should not be using string formatting to insert values into an SQL string. The OP is using placeholders for a parameterized query.